# Tomato Firmware on Asus RT-N12

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, tomato

Has anyone gotten any luck with installing Tomato Firmware on an Asus RT-N12 and/or get WiFi 802.11n working?

It seemed to flash correctly using the Asus Firmware and DD-WRT runs fine but it won't establish a connection or give out IP addresses when I flash it with Tomato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My steps (generalized):

1. Get Asus Firmware Upgrade Tool
2. Installed DD-WRT Mini v24 pre-sp2
3. Downloaded tomatousb no-usb std (tomato-K26-1.27.9047MIPSR2-beta16-Std)
4. Renamed the the file extension to .bin
5. Used DD-WRT upgrade screen

Found some guides:

- http://www.linksysinfo.org/forums/showpost.php?p=358080&postcount=278
- http://www.xtremecoders.org/2010/04/tomato-nd-usb-mod-with-kernel-2-6-beta-11-by-teddy-bear/
- http://tomatousb.org/doc:build-types
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomatousb/files/